# Java data structure where elements automatically removed after specified delay for every element

Tags: java, data-structures, queue, guava, blockingqueue

Does anybody know if there is existing Java data structure where elements are automatically removed from it based on the delay for each element? In other words, each element has its own ttl.

For example:

```
public class DataStructureWithDelay {

    void add(Object element, long delay) {} 
    // After delay expires element will be removed from data structure automatically
}

DataStructureWithDelay dataStructure = new DataStructureWithDelay()
dataStructure.add(element, 10000L)
```

Comment: Use e.g. a cache with a time based eviction strategy.

Comment: Redis allows you to specify a TTL on a key

Comment: This is just going to devolve to a priority queue with "time-of-death" as the sort key.  Caches that allow custom specified eviction times will degenerate to this too.

Comment: @LouisWasserman But how can we make priority queue to remove element as soon as ttl is expired?

Comment: @luk2302 But the time based eviction strategy will be the same for all elements in such cache, right? How can we make ttl for every record different?

Comment: By implementing one.

Comment: You pretty much just have to have a thread, or at least use a `ScheduledExecutorService`.

Comment: But you don't need to remove the item from the priority queue as soon as it expires. You can remove expired items during addition of new items or when you query the queue to get the next item.